# Como ordenar determinado objeto de um array por ordem alfabética?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Olá! Sou iniciante e estou fazendo um site com HTML + CSS + JS e preciso ordenar alguns itens.
É um site fictício que tem como objetivo pegar os pokemons que já estão sendo apresentados e ordenado por ID. Meu desafio e por isso preciso da ajuda de vocês para saber como fazer com que "**quando o usuário clicar no select "A-Z", essa visualização deve reordenar utilizando como critério o nome do pokemon"** por ordem alfabética, caso clique em Z-A, a apresentação seja na ordem alfabética reversa.

[Segue link do git hub](https://github.com/YaOliveira/data-lovers-pokemon)

Estou utilizando os dados do **src/data/pokemon** tem o arquivo pokemon.js que estou utilizando os dados para apresentar no site.

**Grata pela ajuda!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ola, vc pode usar o editor para informar trecho de código do que já tentaste ... normalmente a comunidade não visita serviços externos para avaliar código. O próprio editor possui um *snippet* para rodar trechos de HTML, CSS e JavaScript. Eu recomendo reformular sua questão.

Comment: array.sort() https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort Você pode tentar outros métodos também...

Comment: Obrigada, farei isso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dando uma olhada no seu código, o que você pode fazer é utilizar o método `addEventListener` para executar novamente sua função `showPokemon` toda vez que o `select` for alterado.

Aí você pode pegar o valor do campo do select pra saber se vai ser crescente ou decrescente e usar o método `sort` para ordenar.

Avisa aqui nos comentários se conseguiu ou se ainda tiver alguma dúvida :)

Como você disse que ainda está começando, vou deixar alguns links de referências:

Método `addEventListener`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener

Método `sort`:

https://www.javascriptprogressivo.net/2019/01/Metodo-sort-Ordenar-array-JS.html

Comment: Olá! Muito obrigada por olhar meu código e fazer as orientações. Estava totalmente perdida. Vou seguir suas dicas, qualquer coisa te aviso.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `.map()` e `.sort()` para criar uma lista de nomes em ordem alfabética, exemplo:

```
let crescent = POKEMON["pokemon"].map(object => {
    return object.name
}).sort()
```

E usar `.slice()` para copiar esta lista crescente e `.reverse()` para ordenar de forma decrescente, exemplo:

```
let decrescente = crescente.slice().reverse()
```

Estas listas apresentam apenas nomes pelos quais podes pesquisar em sua matriz de pokemons dentro de uma iteração usando `.find()`, exemplo:

```
crescente.forEach(poke => {
    return POKEMON["pokemon"].find(x => x.name === poke)
})
```

---

O **snippet** de código abaixo é simples mas acho que se enquadra em sua necessidade:

```js
// resevar o elemento <select>
let select = document.getElementById('sort-menu')

// reservar a <div> para mostrar pokemons
let container = document.getElementById('container')

// reservar a lista de pokemons
const listPokemons = POKEMON["pokemon"]

// matriz de nomes em ordem alfabética
let ascending = listPokemons.map(obj => {
    return obj.name
}).sort()

// matriz de nomes em ordem reversa (cópia, não modifica a original)
let descending = ascending.slice().reverse()

// função para mostrar pokemons
function showPokemons(pokeInfo) {
    let template = `<img src="${pokeInfo.img}" width="75px">`
    container.innerHTML += template
}

// função iterar (crescente/decrescente)
function processPokemons(array) {
    // loop
    array.forEach(poke => {
        // mostrar
        showPokemons(listPokemons.find(x => x.name === poke))
    })
}

// observar evento no seletor
select.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    // limpar container
    container.innerHTML = ''
    
    switch(evt.target.value){
    
        // crescente (e por padrão)
        case 'a-z':
        default:
            processPokemons(ascending)
            break
        
        // decrescente
        case 'z-a':
            processPokemons(descending)
            break
     }
}, false)

// pre-carregar lista crescente por padrão
window.onload = function() {
    processPokemons(ascending)
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://daianalugocarvalho.github.io/data-lovers/src/data/pokemon/pokemon.js"></script>

<select id="sort-menu">
    <option value="none">Ordenação:</option>
    <option value="a-z">A - Z</option>
    <option value="z-a">Z - A</option>
</select>

<div id="container"></div>
```

---

Fonte:

- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)